# Get max from series of input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, max

I have a series of input fields. I never know how many, so I need to get the value from a class. In this case the class is `.total`.

The `bestresult` is a text field that gets it's value from `mysql`, but I want it to be changed manually or by the highest value from the other text fields.

This is the code. Does not work obviously, but maybe you get the idea of what I want to do.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input.total').change(function()
{
    var max = $('.total').max();
    $('#bestresult').attr("value", max);
});
</script>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="bestresult" id="bestresult" class="total" value=""><br>
<input type="text" name="resultat[100][total]" class="total" value=""><br>
<input type="text" name="resultat[121][total]" class="total" value=""><br>
<input type="text" name="resultat[130][total]" class="total" value="">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should have your script at the end of your body, in order to have the elements defined when you bind the change event.

Then, you'd better filter the input, to exclude the one containing the max. You can use this selector : `input.total[id!=bestresult]`.

And it would be better to bind also the keyup event, so that the max is updated without the user having to click outside.

Thus, you can have this code :

```
$('input.total[id!=bestresult]').on('blur change keyup', function(){
    $('#bestresult').attr("value", Math.max.apply(null, $('.total[id!=bestresult]').map(function(){
        return parseFloat(this.value)}).slice().filter(function(i, v){return v==v})
    ));
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/k9CGp/)

Comment: I can not exclude bestresult. It may be change manually. So bestresult can be higher the the highest input field if that made any sence :-)

Comment: OK, that made sense. In this case you can take this code and remove the filter on id.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you very much. Two days of frustration over.

Comment: My code is a little compact. If a point isn't clear, don't hesitate to ask a precision.

Comment: "First, you should have your script at the end of your body". Saints preserve us, what do you think `$(function(){...});` is for.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot If your script is yet in the body, it's cleaner to simply put it below. Maybe you didn't see it, but the ready callback wasn't used in OP's code.

Comment: As I said, "saints preserve us".

Answer (score 3):

The solution is very simple. Try this:

```
$('input.total').change(function()
{
     var max = 0;

     $('.total').each(function(){
          if(parseFloat($(this).val()) > max ) {
               max = parseFloat($(this).val());
          }
     });

     $('#bestresult').val(max);
});
```

But if you have multiple textboxes, you should keep track of the max value and update every time change event is triggered to achieve better performance.

```
    var max = 0;

    // get the max for the first time
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.total').each(function () {
            if (parseFloat($(this).val()) > max) {
                max = parseFloat($(this).val());
            }
        });

        $('#bestresult').val(max);
    });

    $('input.total').change(function () {
        if (parseFloat($(this).val()) > max) {
            max = parseFloat($(this).val());
        }

        $('#bestresult').val(max);
    });
```